# Правильно ли я понял условие задачи

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вариант 1)

```
var n = 20;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

вариант 2)

```
var n = 20;
for (var i = 2; i < n; i++)
```

но верный как я понимаю вариант 2, где 2 < n значит что в условии цикла надо писать i=2 а не i=0) ?

Полный код откуда выдернут цикл

```js
    var n = 20;

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     var str = "";
     var toy = -1; 

     if (i % 2 !== 0) {
      toy = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 * i + 1)) + 1;
     }

     for (var y = 1; y <= (2 * i + 1); y++) {
      if(toy == y) {
       str += 'o';
      } else {
       str += '*';
      } 
     }

       for (var z = 1; z < n - i; z++) {
      str = "_" + str + "_";
     }
 
     console.log(str);
    }
```

Comment: похоже на правду, потому что исходя из условия рисовать нужно начинать только если n больше 2, и что-то мне подсказывает что нужно начать с n=3, потому что при первом проходе цикла вы уже начнете рисовать. 
Если начинать с n=2, а по условию 2<n, то у нас получается на 1 проход больше, потому что вы используете i++ и на первом проходе мы получим 2=2, а не 2<3

Comment: Какой вариант цикла правильный зависит от того, что делается в цикле. Но в этом случае неправильны оба варианта, т.к. ``n`` равно не 20.

Comment: @Эникейщик выше я добавил полный код откуда выдернул этот цикл

Comment: @Эникейщик да я увидел что в комментариях оно не очень вышло...поэтому написал код выше

Comment: Начинать надо, конечно же, с нуля. Если начинать с 2, то и вывод начнется не с верхушки, а с середины.

Comment: @Эникейщик т.е. по сути код с решением задачи соответствует условию, верно ?

Comment: Не совсем. Высота елки должна вводиться вручную и она не может быть 20 или больше (в текущей версии как раз 20).

Comment: Откуда, кстати, задача? Уже раз пять за последний месяц тут была.

Comment: @Эникейщик тестовое задание от фирмы чтобы попасть к ним на обучалку,  Кажется понял о чем вы, в общем поскольку цикл начинается с var i=0, то выше должно быть n=19, т.к. ноль тоже считается. А вот если бы была другая задача без рисунков, то можно было бы указать n=20, но тогда бы пришлось начинать цикл с var i=1, я правильно понял ?

Comment: Ну примерно так, да.

Comment: @Эникейщик а есть разница var toy = -1; или вполне можно указать var toy = 0; ? вроде бы по результату одно и тоже, или это страховка что если вдруг будет умножение/деление на 0 ?

Comment: В этом коде нет. Там дальше сравнивается с y, а y начинается с 1. Деления на toy нигде нет.